# iOS large file download ~1GB files

Tags: ios, download, large-files

For my bachelor thesis I have to implement an eLearning app for iOS. As you can see in my title, I have to download a file in the documents directory that has a size of nearly 1 or 2 GB. I'm very new at iOS-Development, so I would appreciate every tip how i can handle that.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I've already read a lot about NSUrlConnection and ASIHTTPRequest... but I don't know if it is possible to implement this with one of these two options!

Comment: Is this a single file? or there are n numbner of files? What do you want to do with these files later on from your app?

Answer (score 1):

Its good that you have read about `NSURLConnection` and `ASIHTTP`. But as you must be aware ASIHTTP is no longer actively developed/maintained. `NSURLConnection` is good to understand and learn the basics.

For day to day use, I'd suggest you use `AFNetworking`. It is simple to use and contains example for understanding how to use it.

For downloading large files it is recommended to write the downloaded data directly to a file rather than storing it in the memory. Using [`AFNetorking` you can do this by](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#how-do-i-download-a-file),

```
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"download.zip" append:NO];
```

I have not tried downloading that large data myself, but I'm sure this will be a good start point for you.

**AFNetworking**: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking 
**API documentation**: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0-RC2/

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this will very likely take a while to download I would definitely recommend doing this asynchronously using `NSURLRequests` and `NSURLConnections`.

My biggest concern though, is the pure size of this download and how this will likely not fit into RAM so this download may not actually be as easy as it seems. You can give it a shot, but what I would recommend is breaking this into multiple files/downloads if possible.

I will post code in a minute when I find code I have previously written.

**Added Code**

First off, make your class that needs to do the downloading to be an `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `` `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate ``.

Then you can implement the download request as follows.

```
NSMutableData *linkData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *linkRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:youURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:linkRequest delegate:self];
```

The variable `linkData` should really be declared in the interface file and then allocated in the implementation, but for brevity I just created it as above.

Then you need the following methods which will be called

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [linkData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
     // handle a fail
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // do what you need when download finishes
}
```